# Why do we need to use Zookeeper for a Coordination Service instead of just a central database?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-system

Quoting the zookeeper [docs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.7/zookeeperOver.html)

> ZooKeeper is a distributed, open-source coordination service for
> distributed applications. It exposes a simple set of primitives that
> distributed applications can build upon to implement higher level
> services for synchronization, configuration maintenance, and groups
> and naming.
>
> Guarantees
>
> ZooKeeper is very fast and very simple. Since its goal, though, is to
> be a basis for the construction of more complicated services, such as
> synchronization, it provides a set of guarantees. These are:
>
> ```
> Sequential Consistency - Updates from a client will be applied in the order that they were sent.
> Atomicity - Updates either succeed or fail. No partial results.
> Single System Image - A client will see the same view of the service regardless of the server that it connects to.
> Reliability - Once an update has been applied, it will persist from that time forward until a client overwrites the update.
> Timeliness - The clients view of the system is guaranteed to be up-to-date within a certain time bound.
> ```

But I don't see any new problem that Zookeeper solves apart from being highly fault tolerant compared to a central database. All the guarantees that zookeeper assures can be guaranteed in a central database too.

Atomicity -> As it's a single node. all updates are atomic.

Sequential Consistency -> after an update clients can wait until the ack until they send the next update to maintain the sequence.

Single System Image, Reliability, Timeliness -> guaranteed as it's a single node.

So, Avoiding a single point of failure is the only main advantage of using zookeeper. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper (and other consensus based systems) offers sequential consistency, strong consistency and high availability.

"apart from being highly fault tolerant" that's actually huge - the fault tolerance.

If you don't care about availability, you totally can use any other linearizable storage - even a directory with files will work.

Consensus based system, and systems based on them (e.g. zoo + your own code) are used to implement machine state replication. All transitions are stored in a distributed log - to make it durable there are many copies. Consensus is about what is the order of event in the log.

With the log being available, the actual business code can consume events and change its state machine - typical state machine transitions. Since each copy of log has the same sequence of events, all states machines will get to the same state.

The key thing is about timing - all logs will get same events in the same order, but there is no guarantee when that happens - a node could be disconnected from the network, hence its log will be stale, and by extension the state machine as well.

To see the true latest value, as you would expect with a singe source of truth, you have to use linearizable read. One way of doing this is to append the read operation to the log itself and wait for it to be committed. Read do nothing with state machines, but the fact that a reader placed something to log and got it committed, that signals that the entire log is read - there is no stale data. (Stale it means that all writes happened before the read are reflected, while read is happening, new writes could happen).

All of this complexity comes form the availability requirements - a cluster with three nodes can let one node to go down, without affecting operations.

So, yes, you could use any linear storage to do the same, ignoring availability. You could do this by keeping the log of events in a table, and every client to track a pointer (or id) of last applied operation; so every client could go and move its own state machine.